# Why is destructor always declared virtual

Tags: c++, destructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)
>   [Virtual destructor and undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599225/virtual-destructor-and-undefined-behavior)

i am new to c++ and programming,i have observed that destructor is always declared virtual.
may i know why is it so?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the search before posting new questions; many have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's declared virtual so that inheriting classes will remember to override this method to do their own cleanup. This is important to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Wrong. destructors cannot be overloaded.

Comment: This is a mean to allow upper in the chain of inheritance pointer to call its own destructor method, ie. BaseClass* ptr = new DerivedClass(); delete ptr;

So it will let "ptr" to correctly call the correct destructor method of its own.

Answer (score 13):

It is **not** *always* declared `virtual`. It is declared virtual when you want to `delete` an object through a pointer which of type base class, then it is required to make the destructor of base class virtual, to avoid undefined behavior.

```
class A{ public: ~A(); }; //note:  ~A() is not virtual
class B : public A {};

A *pA = new B();

delete pA; //invokes undefined behavior, as ~A() is not declared virtual
```

In such cases, you need to make the base class destructor virtual:

```
class A{ public: virtual ~A(); }; //note:  ~A() is virtual
class B : public A {};

A *pA = new B();

delete pA; //Well defined behavior, as ~A() is declared virtual
```

In this case, `delete pA` will first invoke `~B()` (because `pA` is pointing to an object of type `B`), then it will invoke `~A()`.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are not always declared `virtual`.

A `virtual` destructor is important if a class is intended to be used as a *`public`* base class. Without a `virtual` destructor, the following would not work:

```
class A {public: ~A() {} };

class B : public A {public: ~B() {}};

A *a = new B;
delete a;
```

The last line will not do the right thing, because it will *not* call `B`'s destructor. To correct this, `A`'s destructor must be `virtual`.

Note that this is only necessary for classes that you *intend* to be derived from, and those that you intend the user to use `public` inheritance. This generally is not the case for most classes.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of inheritance it makes sense to make a destructor as virtual for the base class so as the proper class object is freed when a destructor for that particular class is called through a base class pointer. So, it follows the reverse order of inheritance. (child to parent)